# Decision tree (recursive type)

Tags: f#

I'm stuck with one of the examples from "Real World Functional Progamming", chapter 8 -- decision trees. If I run this code in FSI (version 4.1)

```
type QueryInfo = {
  Title: string
  Positive: Decision
  Negative: Decision
}
and Decision =
  | Result of string
  | Query of QueryInfo

let rec tree = 
    Query({ Title = "A"
            Positive = aleft; Negative = aright })
and aleft = 
    Query({ Title = "B"
            Positive = bleft; Negative = Result("Yes") })
and aright =
    Query({ Title = "C"
            Positive = Result("No"); Negative = Result("Yes") })
and bleft =
    Query({ Title = "D"
            Positive = Result("No"); Negative = Result("Yes") })

printfn "%A" tree
```

the value `tree` is

```
val tree : Decision = Query {Title = "A";
                            Positive = null;
                            Negative = null;}
val aleft : Decision = Query {Title = "B";
                              Positive = null;
                              Negative = Result "Yes";}
val aright : Decision = Query {Title = "C";
                              Positive = Result "No";
                              Negative = Result "Yes";}
val bleft : Decision = Query {Title = "D";
                              Positive = Result "No";
                              Negative = Result "Yes";}
```

the values for `Positive` and `Negative` for the first two nodes are `null`, instead of references declared below (`aleft`, `aright`, `bleft`). Hence a function to parse the tree would fail.

How should I define the (recursive) type of a decision tree, in order to obtain a tree structure value?

```
val tree : Decision = Query {Title = "A";
                            Positive = aleft;
                            Negative = aright;}
val aleft : Decision = Query {Title = "B";
                              Positive = bleft;
                              Negative = Result "Yes";}
...
```

Comment: This question is very interesting. I'm unable to find docs on how `and` should behave with `let`.  It seems like your code should either throw an error, or what you attempted should work and you've uncovered a bug.

Comment: As an aside I don't think the `rec` keyword is needed in your definition of `tree`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly it doesn't look like you need a recursive value here. You should be able to just define the entire tree at once:

```
let tree = 
  Query { Title = "A"
          Positive = Query { Title = "B"
                             Positive = Query { Title = "D"
                                                Positive = Result("No")
                                                Negative = Result("Yes") }
                             Negative = Result "Yes" }
          Negative = Query { Title = "C"
                             Positive = Result "No"
                             Negative = Result "Yes" } }
```

Printing `tree` yields this output:

```
Query {Title = "A";
       Positive = Query {Title = "B";
                         Positive = Query {Title = "D";
                                           Positive = Result "No";
                                           Negative = Result "Yes";};
                         Negative = Result "Yes";};
       Negative = Query {Title = "C";
                         Positive = Result "No";
                         Negative = Result "Yes";};}
```

Comment: Another option is to declare `tree` starting from leaves to root, which eliminates the need for `and` in the original example.

Comment: Indeed both workarounds are valid, but the original code (which compiles correctly in F#4.1!) has a certain beauty ;-) One might even use a sub-tree just by direct reference to an intermediate node, instead of looking it up by Title.

Answer (score 3):

This looks very much like a compiler bug.

Here's a shorter repro:

```
type A = A of B
and B = B of A | C

let rec a = B (A b)
and b = B (A c)
and c = C
```

Initialization here fails in the same way: `a = B (A null)`.

Filed [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/847), let's see what response I get.

Comment: It might be so, a compiler bug. Using F# version 4.0 like here [https://repl.it/@leonistor/RecDecisionTree](https://repl.it/@leonistor/RecDecisionTree) produces the desired result, as shown by @taylor-wood above.